# SSIS package connection is not working in sql server agent

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, db2-400, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to connect to a AS/400 system with a IBM DB2 for i5/OS IBMDA400 OLE DB Provider as a connector.

I want to write data to a table in the AS/400 system and read data from the same location. So I build a package that writes data from a sql server db on a SQL Server 2008r2 to the AS/400 system.

This works perfectly in Visual Studio, but when I add this package to an existing package with a Execute Package Task and the existing package get called by the sql server agent. I get the following error:

> Error message: Failed to acquire connection "connection_name". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

Can someone help me?

Things that I tried and didn't work:

1. Delayvalidation on True for the package and the connection.
2. Run job in 32 bit mode
3. Change the protection level

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about `SSIS`, so what is your naming convention? The dialog says `0`, but is that `system` or `SQL` naming? Why it matters: Only `System` naming supports the `Library List` for finding unqualified tables.

Comment: Did you try to `Ping` your server using the server name?

Comment: Yes, when I run it in Visual Studio the package runs. Uses the connection and writes data to the AS400. There is a difference I think between the user, because the sql server agent uses a serviceaccount and the solution the permissions of the user logged in. Only in the connection is a different user set that has acces to the AS/400 system

Comment: Did you look at the logs on the server? You should be able to find a job named `QZDASOINIT` for your user id, and view it's logs. If you have `Navigator` you can look under Work Management -> Server Jobs. If you are on green screen you can use `WRKACTJOB SBS(QUSRWRK)`.

Comment: I don't have permission on the AS400 and the developer is not around. I found a workaround. I use the OPENQUERY function with a linked server. Now I don't need a connector anymore in my SSIS package

Comment: Excellent work by hitting the most common issue (32 bit only drivers but agent job defaults to 64 bit execution) The next thought would be "do you have the *exact* same version of the driver?" I've run into situations where a point release difference caused the package to not work on a server (dev was 19.304.008 and server was 19.304.007)